# after adding Telegram.Bot From nuget, MVC fails on compile

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook, system.web.http

i'm using vs2012 and created a MVC4 project

i'm going to implement a webhook for telegram bot.

but after i added Telegram Bot Api from nuget, my projects not compiles fully and throws an exception like below:

> Attempt by method 'System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration..ctor(System.Web.Http.HttpRouteCollection)' to access method 'System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration.DefaultFormatters()' failed.

i found some solutions on stackoverflow but they couldn't helped me.
some one siad uninstall and install WebApiClient but it had no affects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just commented this code in Global.asax.cs and it's working truly...

```
WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
```